# Alexa custom skill not giving answers to the default queries

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have created a custom skill for Alexa. I can able to get the response for custom skills also. But I'm getting one issue.

I have created a simple skill with invocation FullName and intent FullNameIntent which has the utterance like **What is my full name**, then it's returning my full name. But next query, if I'm asking **what is the time now**, it's giving answers again full name only.

My expected  answer is **current time**  as response.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create separate intent and sample utterances for 'what is the time now'. As you didn't mention anything about the intent for the time I believe you don't have an intent and sample utterance for the same.